# Why is managed metadata 'suggestions' only working as "begins with" and not "contains"?

Tags: calendar, managed-metadata, form

We have managed metadata working for a field where we love the auto-complete\suggestions ability. We're currently using this to populate a form (calendar entry) and enter in contact names. The problem is that the auto-complete, or Suggestions, that show up as you type only work if you start typing the same way the data is entered. So I cannot type a person's last name and have it show up as a Suggestion, I have to type the first name. In the screen shot below:

- I can type **Jon** and find **Jon C. Yoder**
- I can type **Jon C.** and find **Jon C. Yoder**
- I *cannot* type **Jon Yod** and find who I want
- I *cannot* type **Yoder** and find who I want

[image]

Any ideas for how to make this work the way I want?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is default behavior.  One way you could achieve what you are trying to do is add the last name as a synonym to the full name in the term store.  That would allow you to search for last name as well.  You could also add a synonym for the full name that excluded the middle initial.

[image: Example]

As you can see, since safety is a synonym for Patient Safety, it returns Patient Safety.  If Yoder was a synonym for Jon Yoder, your search on last name would work.

Depending on how you are populating the term store with Contacts, that may not be feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is just an example of how we want to use this feature, there are plenty of other (multi-word) items like company names etc. Basically we want it to do a "contains" not a "starts with"